# Selenium php-webdriver check attribute after click

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

```
<a class="lnk" href="http://www.google.com">Go Google</a>
```

When click on this link, another css class 'loading' will append. How do we test this before redirecting to google.com.

```
$element = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('lnk'));
$element->click();
```

Is there any way to check the class attribute contains 'loading' before redirecting to destination?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript to edit the `href` attribute and add it timeout

```
$element = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('lnk'));
$href = $element->getAttribute('href');
$script = "javascript:setTimeout( function() { window.location = {$href} }, 5000 );"
$driver->executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('href', arguments[1]);", $element, $script);
```

Now yo have enough time to check if `class` attribute contains `loading`

```
$element = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('lnk'));
$class = $element->getAttribute('class');
if (strpos($class, 'loading') !== false) { }
```

Comment: Might not work without an on-click event handler with event.preventDefault invoked in the handler.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with selenium and JavaScript (including English, where all the machine is translated from).
If there is any mistake, please correct me.

I think that the test  click event is difficult to access the connection by default with the click. So as long as we remove the  default click before the test click, you can perform the desired test.
Here is the code:
html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .loading{
            font-size: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a id="google" onclick="loading()" href="https://google.com">Google</a>
</body>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function loading()
    {
        $("#google").attr('class', 'loading');
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Test Code:

```
<?php
use Facebook\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxProfile;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

include './vendor/autoload.php';

$profile = new FirefoxProfile();

$caps = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$caps->setCapability(FirefoxDriver::PROFILE, $profile);

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('localhost:4444/wd/hub', $caps);

$driver->get("http://localhost/test.php");

$element = $driver->findElement(\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::id('google'));

//Cancel the default click event to perform the test
$driver->executeScript('   document.testLinkClick = function (event){ event.preventDefault() }   ');
$driver->executeScript('   $("#google").bind( "click", document.testLinkClick ); ');

$element->click();

$driver->wait(3, 500)->until(function () use ($element){
    $class = $element->getAttribute('class');
    if (strpos($class, 'loading') !== false) return true;
}, 'error');

//Restore the default click event to perform subsequent tests
$driver->executeScript('$("#google").removeClass("loading")');
$driver->executeScript('$("#google").unbind("click", document.testLinkClick)');

$element->click();    //继续你的测试
```

Forgive my machine translation english english